# Search the corresponding cell in a worksheet and input an entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I did like to know how to search a cell based on a date entry,that serves as a holidays list. For example Christmas:25-12-2013. 
Can you give me VB program that will address the 12th row and 25th column in a worksheet and enter "holiday" in that cell. Also if possible I would like this program to run for other entries in this list, like New Year:01-01-2013, May Day:01-05-2013 etc.. and stop at blank cell in the holidays list

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
cells(12,25)
```

to address row 12 in column 25 in VBA. Are you trying to build a calendar? What about dates in 2014? What are you trying to achieve? You need to provide more detail and maybe step back from the immediate problem and present the bigger picture.

There are many calendar spreadsheets out there and many ways to manage holidays from a list of dates.